# How to make a table editable in a keynote template?

Tags: keynote

When adding Images, Text & Shape to a Master slide you have the option of **Define as Media Placeholder**.

No such option (appears to) exists if you add a Table to a master slide. This means that when someone adds a slide from a template which contains a table it is non-editable.

Is there anyway of adding a Table to a Master Slide which allows that table to remain editable?

Answer (score 1):

No.

The only thing you can do is to add an object placeholder to the master so that the table gets inserted with the desired position/dimensions.

Plus a table style with the desired color scheme. If you then delete all the default table styles, your custom table style gets applied when inserting the table into the slide.